# Change the label text via javascript without having id

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make change to label text. But as id I am unable to understand what am I missing as it is not changing the text from English to Spanish. Can anyone help with this one?

```
<td width="125">
    <span class='Normal'>
        <span class="FormText">
            <label for='txt4506'>First Name:</label>
        </span>
        <span class='required'>*</span>
    </span>
</td>
```

I wanted to change this way.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

            var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
            [].forEach.call(tds, function(td) {
            if (td.textContent.trim() == 'First Name:')
                {
                td.textContent = 'Nome:';
                }
            });  
    });
```

Comment: You should probably set the content of the _label_ instead of the `<td>`.  The td is only there to assist in layout, it is the label that is the meaningful element. (and... using tables for layout?) And, you may be able to combine into one span that has both classes, as `<span class="Normal FormText">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging 101: Look at the value you are trying to match

```
console.log(td.textContent.trim());
```

gives:

```
First Name:

      *
```

`trim()` only removes trailing and leading whitespace.

---

Target the label instead, and use a regular expression to match the bit you care about:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tds = document.querySelectorAll('label');
  [].forEach.call(tds, function(td) {
    td.textContent = td.textContent.replace(/First Name/, "Nome");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="125">
      <span class='Normal'>
        <span class="FormText">
            <label for='txt4506'>First Name:</label>
        </span>
      <span class='required'>*</span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   //A much understandable answer!!


 <td width="125">
        <span class='Normal'>
            <span class="FormText">
                <label for='txt4506'>First Name:</label>
            </span>
            <span class='required'>*</span>
        </span>
    </td>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var tds=$('span>label');
            for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++){
                if($(tds[i]).text().match(/\bFirst Name\b/)){
                    console.log($(tds[i]).text()+' is matched!');

                    //now do what u want...
                    $(tds[i]).text('New text')
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you're missing the colon in your if statement. Try:

```
        if (td.textContent.trim() == 'First Name:')
```

Answer (score -3):

you must select what's unique. That's what everyone does while selecting a DOM element( isn't it so?? ;) ). So do this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector("label[for='txt4506']");
elem.innerHTML = "some text";
```

Comment: This will not work as there many different labels which uses same for.

Comment: Then you are not using the label tag properly. As for one form, there should be unique "name" attribute for each form element. A label is given for a particular form element, say input or textarea, therefore for a form there will always be unique labels. Thus, you can get your label as per the above answer. Else you should not use label just like that, it has a very specific purpose. Like clicking on label automatically clicks on checkbox or radio button.